# How to acces SlidingTabLayout XML views on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

my name is Augusto, I'm developing a Messaging/Social app for Android on **Android Studio** and I implemented SlidingTabLayout (`com.google.samples.apps.iosched.ui.widget`) with 2 tabs (Chats and Friends ).

I wish to know how to access the views inside the Tabs' xml files on my activity.

I have:
`MainActivity.class` with `activity_main.xml` as contentview and the tabs's layouts(`friendsview.xml` and `chatsview.xml`) for the tabs.

I want to access tabs' layouts view (e.g: `EditText`, `ImageView`) from `MainActivity.class`, How do I "import" them to the activity?

Thanks!

Comment: That sample is old. Use the new design support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SlidingTabLayout` it's only a layout. To manage content use fragments with `FragmentPagerAdapter` for your tabs.

[Here (link)](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) is nice tutorial for you.

If you follow this example tutorial, you will have

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

and to access `EditText` and other widget inside tab, you need to have reference from view, so change above code to:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

private EditText editText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatsview,container,false);
        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_EDIT_TEXT_ID);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, Thank You a lot! I forgot that the tabs had Classes xD. Helped a lot

Comment: Well. You can be very tricky and go in very bad way by using only one fragment with two big layouts, which are changing visibility from `VISIBLE` to `GONE` dependings which tab is selected. But like I said, it's very bad performance idea. Anyway, if your problem is solved, mark "tick" near answer.